# Exclude Debit Transactions

Tags: oracle

I have a need to select records from transactions table excluding certain transactions.

Bellow is a sample output of my tables.

```
TB_ACCOUNTS     
CUSTCD  ACCTNO  PRDCD
100     10001   SATF
100     10002   SATF
200     10003   CUS

TB_TRANSACTIONS    
TXNNO   TXDATE      ACCTNO  CUSTOMER_NO TXAMT   CASHFLOWTYPE
TX1     18-Jul-16   10001   100         5000    CR
TX2     18-Jul-16   10002   100         5000    DR
TX3     18-Jul-16   10003   200         3000    DR
TX4     18-Jul-16   10001   100         3000    CR
```

I want to select credit transactions where PRDCD is 'SATF' and exclude transfers between own accounts. For example customer 100 PRDCD is SATF and has two accounts. I want my select query to exclude credit transaction of amount 5000 because the debit account also belongs to the same customer. But include credit transaction of 3000 amount because the debit account is of different customer and type is not SATF.

So far I got bellow query but the output I'm getting is completely wrong.

```
select * from TB_TRANSACTIONS AB inner join TB_ACCOUNTS AC
on AB.ACCTNO=AC.ACCTNO
where AB.CASHFLOWTYPE='CR'
and AC.PRDCD='SATF'
and AB.TXNNO=
(select TXNNO from TB_TRANSACTIONS A, TB_ACCOUNTS B
where A.ACCTNO=B.ACCTNO
and A.TXAMT=AB.TXAMT
and A.CASHFLOWTYPE='DR'
and B.PRDCD=AC.PRDCD)
```

How to achieve the desired result?

Comment: It would be simple if in your example transactions were numbered TX1, TX1, TX2, TX2. Otherwise how do we know that the first two lines belong to the same transaction and next two to second transaction? Using `txamt` to join rows seems to be suspicious.

Comment: is there a way to relate a given CR trx with its correspondent DR trx?

Comment: @ Ponder Stibbons: TXNNO is not duplicated, it has a unique number, this is where I'm also stuck at

Comment: @ Ricardo Arnold: The only possible way I found was through the amount, otherwise it's not straight forward to relate the DR & CR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like here:

```
select txnno, txdate, acctno, customer_no, txamt, cashflowtype, prdcd
  from (
    select t.*, a.prdcd,
           count(distinct customer_no) over (partition by txdate, txamt) cnt
      from tb_transactions t join tb_accounts a on t.acctno = a.acctno )
  where cnt = 2 and cashflowtype = 'CR' and prdcd = 'SATF'
```

Here I assumed that `txamt` is unique for each date. I strongly suspect that this may be wrong assuption so be warned. 
But there is nothing except this column that tells us that two rows belongs to the same operation.

In first query I used `count()` in analytic version. There are also possible other solutions, for instance `(not) exists`:

```
select *
  from tb_transactions t join tb_accounts a on t.acctno = a.acctno 
  where 
    not exists (
      select 1 from tb_transactions tt join tb_accounts ta on tt.acctno = ta.acctno
        where tt.txdate = t.txdate and tt.txamt = t.txamt
          and tt.cashflowtype = 'DR' and tt.customer_no = t.customer_no)
    and cashflowtype = 'CR' and prdcd = 'SATF'
```

<sup>(sorry for any language mistakes)</sup>